# Distinct Values in hashsets and insert in DataGridView

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview, datasource, except

I want to display a hashset with all the different values ​​between two DataGridView, but I have not been successful in displaying the strings, I attach images.

```
var dataA = new HashSet<string>();
var dataB = new HashSet<string>();
            
for (int i = 1; i < dgv_A.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    dataA.Add(dgv_A[8, i].Value.ToString());
}
            
for (int i = 1; i < dgv_B.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    dataB.Add(dgv_B[8, i].Value.ToString());
}

if (dataA == dataB)
{
    lbl_resultado.Text = "Las certificaciones estan correctas";
}
else
{
     var error = dataA.Except(dataB).Concat(dataB.Except(dataA));
     var container = new HashSet<string>(error);
     dgv_B.DataSource = container.ToList();
}
```

Theres the values that are needed:

[image: Theres the values that are needed]

The result of the code:

[image: Theres the values that are needed]

---

NOTE: the `if (dataA == dataB) part`, it's not the problem i need answer but thanks. The part needed its:

```
else
{
     var error = dataA.Except(dataB).Concat(dataB.Except(dataA));
     var container = new HashSet<string>(error);
     dgv_B.DataSource = container.ToList();
}
```

NOTE 2: The main operation of the project is the verification of documents (for example, that no user has been modified)
If any value is changed you need to know which values ​​were changed.
With

```
 var error = dataA.Except(dataB).Concat(dataB.Except(dataA));
     var container = new HashSet<string>(error);
     dgv_B.DataSource = container.ToList();
```

I get the distinct values ​​fron dataA and dataB, but I can't get it to show me the texts that appear.

NOTE:

[image: The result with correct documents]

Comment: `if (dataA == dataB)` <-- This does not do what you think it does.

Comment: Specifically, that comparison is checking whether those are aliases to the exact same hashset. It does not check whether the elements of the hashset are identical.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are typical values of `dgv_A[8, i].Value.ToString()` ? Because depending on your answer you should use `StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase` or similar instead of the default (pass it in to `HashSet<String>`'s ctor).

Comment: Your `dataA.Except(dataB).Concat(dataB.Except(dataA))` part is also a bad code-smell (it's the same as `( A - B ) + ( B - A )` which is the same thing as `A + B`, so all you need is `dataA.Union(dataB).ToList()`.

Comment: @Dai dgv_A[8, i].Value.ToString() shows the column and rows of an excel sheet, that's why the number 8 because it will always search in the seventh line (worksheets start at index 0,0)

Comment: @RafaelSuazo Index 8 is actually the **ninth** column, not the 7th (the `[Int32, Int32]` indexer is in `columnIndex, rowIndex` order, so `[8, i]` will return the `i`th row's cell in the 9th column.

Answer (score 4):

Here's your problem:

```cs
if (dataA == dataB)
{
}
```

- [The `HashSet<T>` type does not override the `==` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=net-6.0).

  - Consequently `dataA == dataB` performs only a reference equality comparison, which means the same thing as `Object.ReferenceEquals( dataA, dataB  )`, which will **always** be `false`, as `dataA` and `dataB` are references to separate GC objects.
- Instead, [to compare both HashSets to see if they are both equivalent use <sub>(the confusingly named)</sub> `SetEquals()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.setequals?view=net-6.0):

```cs
if( dataA.SetEquals( dataB ) )
{
    lbl_resultado.Text = "Las certificaciones estan correctas";
}
```

- Do not use `Enumerable.SequenceEquals` because that evaluates the `HashSet` as an ordered sequence of values, but a `HashSet` [is a Mathematical Set, which is unordered](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4215574/are-all-sets-ordered-sets#:%7E:text=A%20set%20isn%27t%20ordered,is%20not%20an%20ordered%20set.) and (AFAIK) its `HashSet<T>.Enumerator` iterator returns its elements in *undefined* order, so attempting to check two sets' set-equality by comparing sequences is incorrect.

Comment: Why do you think SetEquals is confusing? Sounds like straightforward application of common naming in set theory. https://www.cs.odu.edu/~toida/nerzic/content/set/basics.html

Comment: @EricJ. Because it's a method, and methods' names generally starting with verbs - for example `GetFoo` and `SetFoo` - so looking at `SetEquals` throws me off because `Set` is a very common verb in method names - so looking at `SetEquals`' name at face-value suggests calling it will mutate an `.Equals` property or something like that. If I had my way, I'd rename `SetEquals` to `AreSetsEqual()` or `IsEqualTo()` or similar.

Comment: Hi @Dai, the part of the problem is looking for distinct  from the two DataGridViews, in the image the data is displayed but it can't be reached.

Comment: @RafaelSuazo I don't understand your problem.

Comment: As they say, two things are hard in computer science: Distributed cache invalidation and naming things.

Comment: @EricJ. yuuuuup  (though personally I've never had any problems implementing cache invalidation schemes, including in (small) distributed systems, so YMMV)

Comment: https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html